# Ошибка на странице предстоящих событий

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На [странице предстоящих встреч сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) мною была замечена ошибка. Цитирую:

> Чтобы получить знак «Не робот» познакомьтесь с сотрудником Stack Overflow **на событие**, которое организовано Stack Overflow или при поддержке Stack Overflow, в котором принимает участие 50 и более человек.

Правильно же надо писать "**на событии**" (см. склонения имен существительных).

Также существует диссонанс между вкладками: "текущие" и "прошлое". Надо бы поменять хотя бы на "прошлые", а еще лучше - "прошедшие".

Comment: С переводами сейчас творится нечто странное. На [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306656/339911) сам чёрт/разработчик ногу сломит. Пока что не представляется возможным поправить упомянутую строку, так как она пропала из списка строк.

Comment: @alexolut, к сожалению, я заметил множество непереведенных строк. Надеюсь, ситуация скоро исправится!

Answer (score 1):

Текст поправлен. Изменения на вкладках отразятся после подхвата переводов и пересборки. Будет так:

> [image: вкладки]